# Background Color Recycled in ListView

Tags: android, listview, background

I have a strange problem. I am setting the background color of the items of a listview like so:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    ...

    if (status == true) {
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,0,85,187));
    }
    else {
        if (morestuff) {
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(128,255,0,0));
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

This seems to work. However, when i scroll on the listview, and then back, some of the rows have acquired a color from another row without being set by this code. I suspect the listview is recycling the views as an optimization.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) will be called all the time when the listview is drawn. Simply taking it will be called when we do a small change example do a small scroll
If you want to set color to a specific row, Just do it by checking the `position` (First argument of getview).

Answer (score 1):

The list view is definately recycling views as an optimization.  You should look at the efficient list view example for ideas.